# Print months from array to a specific year from array

Tags: php

Currently my `$years` array looks like this:

```
$years = array('2013',
               '2014',
               '2015');
```

And thats prints all months from jan to dec. To that that year. But say that i want to print jan to oct for 2015. Then i believe the array has to look something like this:

```
$years = array('2013'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
               '2014'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
               '2015'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
```

so that i can choose how many months i want to print...

But the current code gives me error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in` and the code looks like this:

```
$months = array(
             1=>'januari',
             2=>'februari',
             3=>'mars',
             4=>'april',
             5=>'maj',
             6=>'juni',
             7=>'juli',
             8=>'augusti',
             9=>'september',
             10=>'oktober',
             11=>'november',
             12=>'december');


$years = array('2013'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
               '2014'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
               '2015'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));

echo var_dump($years); //debug, seems right

$data = new stdClass;
foreach($years as $year){
    $data->$year = $months;
}

foreach($data as $year => $months) {
    echo '<b>Year: '.$year.'</b><br>';
    foreach($months as $month) {
        echo 'Month: '.$month.'<br>';
    }
}
```

**My question is:** How can i add an array of months to a specific year?

```
**2013**
jan
...
dec
**2014**
jan
...
dec
**2015**
jan
...
oct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the key for the year, currently you're using the whole array.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
$data = new stdClass;
foreach($years as $year => $yearMonths){
    $data->$year = $yearMonths;
}
```

And I would also suggest a little improvement to the the printing of the data

```
foreach($data as $year => $yearMonths) {
    echo '<b>Year: '.$year.'</b><br>';
    foreach($yearMonths as $month) {
        echo 'Month: '.$months[$month].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Last but not least - you don't need the echo before `var_dump()`

Here's the whole thing working http://ideone.com/4qnqzu